# What is the Best Way to Automate the Launch of a Node.js Webserver after Starting an EC2 Instance?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, service

I'm attempting to automate the start and stop of a Node.js webserver on a Windows EC2 instance that will only run for about 5 months out of the year to avoid operating costs. The method to which I've been able to get this to work is to set a CloudWatch rule that starts and one that stops the EC2 instance on a specific datetime.

As such, I'm trying to get a method working to restart my Node.js webserver whenever the EC2 instance starts. So far I've tried writing a batch script that runs `npm start` in the autostart Windows folder and using the `node-windows` package to create a service that has automated start.

The first method fails as the batch script seemingly only runs when I rdp into the EC2 instance, I need it to run without that needing to happen for minimal maintenance. I *could* go with this solution, but I am a very forgetful person and I know I'm going to fail to remember to rdp into the EC2 instance once a year.

The second method appears to start the service without my intervention (although I'm unable to verify this), but it's not working to launch the Node.js webserver.

I'm fairly certain that I got the configuration for that package correct:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

var svc = new Service({
    name: "webserverautostart",
    description: "Web Server Auto Start",
    script: "C:\\repos\\WEBSITE_FOLDER\\app.js"
});

svc.on('install', function() {
    svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

As for the error I've received:

Event Viewer: Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller

Now, one hypothesis I have as to why this doesn't work is because this service could be running `node app.js` instead of `npm start`, which for reasons I forget now the latter is the one that works, the former does not.

If there's not a way to change that starting command, is there another way I could be going about this?